# random div array change in 2 second

Tags: javascript, random

Hi I have this code can any one know how to change this random keyword in 2 seconds,

```
function shuffle(a, b) {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;

}

var keywords = ["<div>1</div>", "<div>2</div>", "<div>3</div>", "<div>4</div>", "<div>5</div>", "<div>6</div>", "<div>7</div>", "<div>8</div>", "<div>9</div>", "<div>10</div>", "<div>11</div>", "<div>22</div>", "<div>44</div>", "<div>32</div>", "<div>46</div>"];
var randomKeywords = keywords.sort(shuffle);


function luckcricket() {
  document.write(randomKeywords);
  alert('laad');
}


luckcricket();
```

please correct my code. in this code i am not able to see any div's are randomly changing in 2 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want your div's to shuffle periodically.  That is not happening because you are writing `randomKeywords`, which is an array when you invoke `luckcricket`.  What you want to do is either invoke shuffle from within `luckcricket()` or do `document.write(keywords.sort(shuffle))`

```
function shuffle(a, b) {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;

}

var keywords = ["<div>1</div>", "<div>2</div>", "<div>3</div>", "<div>4</div>", "<div>5</div>", "<div>6</div>", "<div>7</div>", "<div>8</div>", "<div>9</div>", "<div>10</div>", "<div>11</div>", "<div>22</div>", "<div>44</div>", "<div>32</div>", "<div>46</div>"];

function luckcricket() {
    // Shift random keywords into callback so it gets updated EVERY TIME
    var randomKeywords = keywords.sort(shuffle);
    document.write(randomKeywords);

    window.setTimeout( function () {
        // Clear after 1 second
        document.body.innerHTML = '';
    }, 1000);
}


luckcricket();
window.setInterval(luckcricket, 2000);
```

Example on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rfRzH/

Comment: i don't need shuffle entire body i need to shuffle only one div potion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Timer,

```
window.setInterval(function() {
// your logic goes here
}, 2000);
```

Every 2 sec your logic will get executed. You can put your code to change the random key here

**UPDATED**
It should have been this way

```
var keywords = ["<div>1</div>", "<div>2</div>", "<div>3</div>", "<div>4</div>", 
        "<div>5</div>", "<div>6</div>", "<div>7</div>", "<div>8</div>", 
        "<div>9</div>", "<div>10</div>", "<div>11</div>", "<div>22</div>", 
        "<div>44</div>", "<div>32</div>", "<div>46</div>"];


function luckcricket() {
    var randomKeywords = keywords.sort(shuffle); 
    document.write(randomKeywords); 
    alert('laad'); 
}

function shuffle(a, b) { 
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1; 
}

window.setInterval(luckcricket, 2000);
```

Comment: it is coming only once after this the screen is just loading :(

Comment: increase the timer value and see

Comment: not working getting same issue

Comment: show us the code what you did. So we'll be in better position to answer. Also open your IE Dev toolbar (or firebugger) to locate script error (if any)

Comment: window.setTimeout(function() {
function shuffle(a, b) {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;

}

var keywords = ["<div>1</div>", "<div>2</div>", "<div>3</div>", "<div>4</div>", "<div>5</div>", "<div>6</div>", "<div>7</div>", "<div>8</div>", "<div>9</div>", "<div>10</div>", "<div>11</div>", "<div>22</div>", "<div>44</div>", "<div>32</div>", "<div>46</div>"];
var randomKeywords = keywords.sort(shuffle);


function luckcricket() {
  document.write(randomKeywords);
  alert('laad');
}


luckcricket();
}, 2000);

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to repeat the function call after a particular time in this way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function() {
       luckcricket();
    }, 2000);
});
```

It will call **luckcricket()** function in every 2 seconds.

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5NKXK/

Comment: but if i add document.write it is not working, how to show my array div's

Comment: I checked, document.write is working. Refer the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5NKXK/4/

Comment: that is loading only once, not changing